# How to avoid optaweb-employee-rostering rebuild persisted data on server restart

Tags: mysql, docker, optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I'm running optaweb-employee-rostering in a dockerized Wildfly server, persisting data with MySql database running in a container too. The .war file is not built in sever's Docker image, it's manually deployed in it via Wildfly's admin interface. Every time container is stopped a restarted, the application rebuild sample data, deleting any data saved during usage, so that the final behavior is the same as ram based storage: the data is lost if the server stops.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior and keep saved data on server restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [the hbm2dll value here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/employee-rostering-server/src/main/filtered-resources/META-INF/persistence.xml#L19) and due to [the Generator's post construct](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/employee-rostering-server/src/main/java/org/optaweb/employeerostering/server/roster/RosterGenerator.java#L347). In the current openshift image there are environment variables to change that.

We're working on streamlining this "getting started" and "putting it into production" experience, as part of the refactor to react / springboot.